# VB.Net Array - Merge array of elements into larger array when element order is different

Tags: vb.net, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Assume I have an array

myArray1 = { A, B, C, D, E, F, …., T}

I have another that contains a subset of the elements of myArray1 but where the order may vary

myArray2= { A, C, H, G, F, M, R, S, T}

I can determine the order of the array elements in myArray1 and myArray2 independently.

How do I merge myArray2 into myArray1 in the correct element order?  The missing elements of myArray1 in myArray2 are assumed to be empty.

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us what the correct element order is?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? If the elements of `myArray2` are a subset of these in `myArray1`, they are already contained. Do you want to have duplicates for elements that occur in both arrays?

Comment: The correct element order is myArray1.  I need to transform myArray2 into myArray1 with the elements in order of myArray1.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that you want to sort `myArray2` into the same order as the elements in `myArray1`? I'm still having trouble understanding your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
''// Contains only the subset of myArray1 that is also in myArray2
Dim intersection As New SortedSet(Of Char)(myArray1)
intersection.IntersectWith(myArray2)

''// Merge back into the first array via a sorted list:
Dim sorted As New List(Of Char)(myArray1)
sorted.AddRange(intersection)
sorted.Sort()
Dim result As Char() = sorted.ToArray()
```

This will result in an array that contains all elements of `myArray1`, plus all elements from `myArray2` that *also* appear in `myArray1` (thus being duplicates in the result), in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those are strings, as in

```
myArray1 = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", …., "T"}
```

then

```
dim d as new dictionary(of string,something)
for each s as string in myarray1
  if not d.containskey(s) then
    d.add(s,something)
  end if
next
for each s as string in myarray1
  if not d.containskey(s) then
    d.add(s,something)
  end if
next
for each s as string in d.keys
  debug.writeline s
next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting version 4 of the Framework, you could use a [`SortedSet(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx).

Otherwise, the simplest solution may be just to create a third array (or, a `List(Of T)`) that contains the elements of the first two arrays, remove any duplicates, and apply whatever sorting algorithm fits your application.

And often times, the simplest solution is the best, unless there's some reason you're going to be doing this over and over in a loop and absolutely need to squeeze the most performance out of it that you can.